# PHP function, call only one variable

Tags: php

I need help with a PHP function im writing. My code:

```
function get_config() {
 $db = dbServer::getInstance();
 $mysqli = $db->getConnection(); 
 $sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM server_config';
 $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $serverStatus = $row['server_status']; 
 $serverTitle = $row['server_title'];
 }
 }
 }
```

Now, If I'd want to call the function and only echo let's say, $serverTitle, how should I do that? I.e:

```
get_config($serverStatus)?
```

I'm a total rookie when it comes to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your function so that it accepts arguments that will be filled with the config values. For instance, if you change the function declaration to:

```
function get_config(&$serverStatus, &$serverTitle){...}
```

Notice the `&` operator next to the parameters. It means that whatever you do to the variables you pass into the functions will survive after the function is finished. So when inside the function you do...

```
 $serverStatus = $row['server_status']; 
 $serverTitle = $row['server_title'];
```

These values will be available after the function is done. You would use the values like this:

```
//call the function, passing in the variables you want filled
get_config($status, $title);
//now, $status and $title have been filled with the DB values
echo $status;
```

**Addendum**

you mentioned in the comments that you like the WordPress approach of calling `get_param('paramName')` to fetch a specific parameter.  The following might work:

```
//you pass an item name (must match a DB column) and function will return
// the item's value
function get_config($item) {
    //static means the next time you call this function,
    //the old value will be remembered. 
    static $row = null;

    //if we fetched the row previously, just get the
    //desired config item. This is a lot more efficient than
    //making a DB query every time the function is called
    if($row) return $row[$item];

    $db = dbServer::getInstance();
    $mysqli = $db->getConnection();
    $sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM server_config';
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);

    //save config data in $row so it will be remembered
    // (because we declared this var as static)
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return $row[$item];//return the item requested
}
```

To use this the function, just pass it the name of the config item you need:

```
$status = get_config('server_status');
```

Or if you just want to echo the configuration

```
echo get_config('server_title');
```

Comment: Ah I see. Great answer! So I need to call the function to fill the variables. Is there a way of echoing the function just like "getStatus('serverTitle')" rather than calling the function first, and then echoing the variable?

Comment: @newbieDevs It's not a good idea to `echo` from within your function (unless that's its purpose) because it really limits the function's usefulness (the calling code may not need results printed to screen; also once you've echoed something to the browser, certain things become impossible to do - setting cookies, starting sessions, setting headers...)  The better design is for the function to return or alter data, and for the calling code, if it wants, to `echo`.  If you really want to `echo` though (eg: during debugging), you can do so from inside the function as the other answer shows you.

Comment: thanks for the help. Really appreciate it. The reason I'm wondering is because I've seen Wordpress using functions like "get_blog_info('name')" to get the title of the page etc, which seemed quite handy, maybe not the title function, but usernames etc.

Comment: @newbieDevs Ok. Getting a variable value is different from `echoing` to the screen. Yes you could design your function to return (not echo) just the config item you want. I've added a bit to my answer to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "Echo" on what you want to return. If you only want one thing then you will have to change up how your query is depending on how many rows there are and maybe add a limit to your query.

```
function get_config() {
$db = dbServer::getInstance();
$mysqli = $db->getConnection(); 
$sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM server_config';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
       $serverStatus = $row['server_status']; 
       $serverTitle = $row['server_title'];

       echo "$serverTitle";
   }
}
}
```